# jssor and display image acording responsiveness

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, jssor

I have a jssor slider that uses two images, one for desktop and another for mobile. The desktop image uses a bootstrap hidden-xs class so it hides on mobile

The problem is that jssor takes the **first** image, the one for desktop and looks bad on mobile (too short in height)

I want jssor to respect hidden-xs so it takes second image

This is because desktop and mobile image uses different **height**

```
<div id="jssor1">
   <div data-u="slides">
      <div>
         <img data-u="image" src="image1" class="hidden-xs" />
         <img data-u="image" src="image2" class="hidden-sm hidden-md hidden-lg" />
      </div>

      /* more divs */

   </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please remove `data-u="image"`, set size and position manually.

Then you can show `image1` for desktop, show `image2` for mobile.

Use `$ScaleSize` to scale slider, thus you can scale slider to different size on mobile and desktop

Comment: It was my very bad. I hardcode the width and height on the jssor and slides. Now I created a class and use media-querys. Thanks